# How to get Log4j Fields List from API

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

How could I get log4j fields list from API for the below properties.
Where I should debug and rootLogger fields from API.

```
log4j.debug=true
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,sysout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some documentation on Log4j2's properties configuration format here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties

However I would encourage you to use the XML format to configure Log4j 2. It is much simpler and easier to read than the Log4j 1.2 XML format, and the vast majority of configuration examples in the manual use the XML format so it is much easier to get started that way: [Lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) , [Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html), [Layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html), ...